# how to make a request like ajax

Tags: ajax, curl

According to [this website](http://sandbox.ala.org.au/datacheck/): I am trying to make a request, send data, and hope to get the result like json format, but not have to be.

In the sandbox page, I've checked the javascript, (I am using Chrome browser, you can go to "resources" -> Frame folder -> sandbox.ala.org.au), it uses AJAX to send and get data.
For example, there is a function (parseColumns), which is using ajax for sending data and getting result.

Is there any other way instead of ajax that could make a request to the server and get the result data? Because I am trying to create an application work similar with the sandbox.

Comment: You could look at websockets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: You can use regular http requests (in the end, this is all the webserver understands), but you may have some work deciphering the inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Leo How can I know which link should I connect to ? in ajax part, I can only see url: dataCheck/parseColumns

Comment: @BrianV How can I know which link should I connect to ? in ajax part, I can only see url: dataCheck/parseColumns

Comment: oh, that's why you need firebug :-) so you can see it's actually http://sandbox.ala.org.au/datacheck/dataCheck/parseColumns and http://sandbox.ala.org.au/datacheck/dataCheck/processData?firstLineIsData=true&headers=Unknown%201&rawData=ABCD

Comment: do like this then. install firebug on your firefox, go the site and enable firebug net tab and see how it deals with it :-) I bet it will make your life way easier :-)

Comment: @Leo how do you find it by the firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative is to make regular http requests. The problem with this approach is that you have to decipher the data format for input and output.

You can see all the request/response traffic in details, from and to your browser, using firebug (https://getfirebug.com/) and enabling the "net" tab

[image]

when you mouse over the "POST" line in the URL column, it shows you the complete URL. Click on the (+) to expand the request item to see details on the request.

[image]

[image]